# Can Qt compiled libs work with newer compilers?

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic-linking

*edit*

Now i am really confused , it works , qt libs compiled with gcc 3.4 works with gcc 8.3.1

I cannot understand why

- End of edit*

I am using same linux qt compiled
runtime libs ,that was originally compiled with an older g++ 3.x.x compiler and it works for now on different linux systems , tested until g++4.8.5 .

Is it by chance? Am i just lucky?

Will it still work with new g++ std 20 compiler .

Or that i should compile from src for each platform...

Qt is 4.7 , can i use the same libs with c++20 compiler ,without build qt from src.

Comment: you'll probably run into https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html at least. Have you tried it? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Thanks for the link it is very informative , thought the std flag is enough, but i see i need to add the define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI

Comment: I didnt , it just worked , cannot understand it

Comment: If you want help or guidance, please include the errors you are getting and preferable a minimal reproducible example. Qt 4.7 is over 11 years old, it's not unthinkable the include files won't even be usable when included, that could be more challenging to fix than to link the libraries. But right now there's no telling what issues you are facing.

Comment: old qt 4.7.1 runtime libraties compiled with gcc 3 DO work with code compiled with gcc 8
this is what i do not understand, how can it be?

specially if there was ABI change at gcc5